# Mapping dummy variables in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, patsy

I have a large DataFrame with 11 columns. I need to convert categorical variables into binary values, so I used `Patsy`:

```
attributes = "admit ~ C(gender) + age + C(ethnicity) + C(state) + gpa + sci_gpa + mcat + C(major) + C(tier) + C(same_ins)"
y, X = dmatrices(attributes, df, return_type="dataframe")
```

This works well. However, I want to test a new sample using data that was stored in the format of the original data frame 
E.g:

```
gender    age    ethnicity    state    gpa    sci_gpa    gre    major    tier    same_ins
male      21     Asian        NV       3.4    3.2        .99    Physics  1       1
```

Is there an easy way to convert this into the same format as X??

Comment: I am not quite familiar with `Patsy`, but if you just want to convert categorical variable into binary values (dummy) in pandas dataframe, then the top level `pandas.get_dummies()` function suits your purpose quite well.

Comment: It is actually important that I convert it into a formula, which Patsy allows me to do. I'm not sure if the get_dummies() allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Patsy stores the meta data for the dmatrix. It can be called via

```
build_design_matrices()
```